# Network Error in Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio, speech-to-text

I'm experimenting with the Demo of the Web Speech API: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html. You'll need version 25.0 of Chrome at least to run it.

I'm trying to use the Web Speech API continuously for a long transcription (10-15 minutes). However, I'm noticing that after roughly 1-2 minutes there is a "network" error (as mentioned in the Web Speech API Spec: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#dfn-onerror).

Does anyone know why this "network" error is happening pretty consistently after 1-2 minutes and if there is any way to configure the Web Speech API for longer, continuous transcriptions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Web speech API usually has 60 seconds of recognition time.

You'll need to call the speechrecognition.onend() method and then call the speechrecognition.start(). So the recognition continues after stop.